# store output of file in variable in powershell

Tags: file, powershell

I have one file say abc.txt and the content of the file is like this :

```
         user1
         user2
         user3
         etc
```

I want to store the content of the file in a variable like this :
user1;user2;user3;user4...

I have used below script in powershell lke this :

```
   $variabl1=([io.file]::readAllText("E:\abc1.txt") -replace "`n")
```

but I am not getting anything when i am using below cmd :

```
            write-host $variabl1
```

I want the value to store in the variable please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because you're not telling `-replace` what to put in place of `\n`. Try:

```
-replace "`n",";"
```

OR

Use `Get-Content` to read the contents into a collection of lines; you can then join that collection (array) with the `-join` operator into a single string.

```
$variabl1 = (Get-content -path "e:\abc1.txt") -join ";"
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but the last ; i m missing...like the output should be user1;user2;user3;user4;  if there are 4 entries in the file upto user4

Comment: Then append a semicolon at the end of the string. You'd have to do the same thing if your input file didn't have a trailing newline.